# Easiest way to generate 32bit Alphanumeric string?

Tags: firebird

In Postgres it's easy:

```
update users set salt = md5(random()::text);
```

But how would you do this on Firebird? I think the solution lies with a combination of these functions:

1. [HASH](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-hash.html)
2. [UUID_TO_CHAR](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-uuid_to_char.html)
3. [RAND](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-udf-rand.html)

Comment: You say Alphanumeric, so what characterset do you want to use?

Comment: select UUID_TO_CHAR(gen_uuid()) from rdb$database